# I need help for design high voltage buck converter

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, high-voltage

I have a 500 Vdc from rectified 3 phase power and then I will make output to 220  V phase to phase 60Hz power. But 500 Vdc doesn't stabilized and Its need to step down to 220 Vdc stabilized.
So, I use buck converter to stabilize and step down. And I will make 3 phase power use inverter after using buck converter.

I have confirmed that this circuit works for now. But I measured PNP bjts Vce and Vbc come out 500 Vdc.
What a nuts! It's completely messed up. I think I'm definitely missing something or everything.  What more do I need to know? The switch topology is wrong? Or buck converter doens't enough  design with this?
[image]

Comment: You're talking about 500VDC and 100A. That's a very dangerous voltage at a serious power level. Based on your question and your comments, you seem not very experienced at designing these things. For your safety and others, I really recommend you do not design and build this yourself. Making this safe is not trivial!

Answer (score 3):

<sub>This answer was made before the OP radically altered his output voltage requirements. However, I've left my answer as it originally stood because the main point I was making that trying to engineer an intermediary supply voltage is irrelevant; the final inverter stage should be designed to cope with the full bus voltage and adjust it's PWM duty cycles accordingly as the DC bus voltage rises or falls.</sub>

> *I have a 500Vdc from rectified 3 phase power and then I will make
> output to 380 V phase to phase 60Hz power*

OK, 380 volts AC is a peak voltage of 537.4 volts if it's to be anything like a sinewave.

> *But 500Vdc doesn't stabilized and Its need to step down to 380Vdc
> stabilized.*

Why bother with the intermediate step of making 380 volts DC when you should be designing your inverter to run from the unstabilized supply.

Also, if you are trying to generate a line voltage of 380 volts AC then this is a peak sine voltage of 537.4 volts and you are going to need at least that voltage applied to your inverter circuit to get anything like 380 volts AC line voltage as a sinewave.

Personally, I think you need to take a step back and examine precisely what DC bus voltage you need. Regards the waveforms in your picture, they look OK but you are interested in the DC voltage across the load or 10 μF capacitor.

Comment: 380VAC phase to phase is 220 VAC phase to ground. I'm sorry.. I edit my question now.
Why make 220Vdc at middle of circuit? Because I want step down and regulate in same time.
And its controlled by MCU later.

Comment: @박성재 you are missing my point. There is no need to produce a stabilized intermediate voltage - just design the inverter to handle the full unregulated voltage and adjust the PWM duty cycles as the unregulated voltage shifts slowly in amplitude.

Comment: @박성재 your question is still contradicting your comment above by the way. Please also note that I answered your original question and now, your alterations are making my answer look stupid so, please roll-back your adjustments and take note - you don't need an intermediary voltage (stabilized or not).

Comment: I appreciate your opinion. But I can't sure it. So I search more information and Asking more than enough this thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I measured PNP bjts Vce and Vbc come out 500Vdc. What a nuts! It's completely messed up.

That is the normal operation of a buck converter. When the switching transistor is off, the collector of your pnp transistor will fall to one diode drop below 0V. Since the emitter is at \$V_{in}\$, \$V_{ce}\$ will be slightly more than \$V_{in}\$.

> The switch topology is wrong?

No.

> Or buck converter doens't enough design with this?

The switching element of a buck converter needs to handle a \$V_{ce}\$ (or \$V_{ds}\$ for a mosfet) of \$V_{in}\$ (plus some). This is normal for a buck converter.

Comment: I got some additional question. Can I replace IGBT instead PNP?
I search the part of PNP but can't find it witch match the condition.
Vce : 700~1000V, Ice : 100A

Comment: Yes, a buck converter can use an IGBT as its switching element. Your output needs to be 100A at 220V? That is 22kW. Are you sure you want to try to design this yourself? Even if you find a switching device that will handle your requirements, and an inductor to handle your requirements, and a bulk capacitor to handle your requirements, you will have a significant problem dissipating the heat generated by your buck circuit. Even if your buck converter were 95% efficient, at full current, it would dissipate over 1kW in heat.

Comment: According first answer, Circuit doens't need intermediary voltage (stabilized or not).
But I want know switch topology using IGBT. Could you get that topology? link to me please..

Comment: The IGBT will go in exactly the same place as your PNP transistor. However you need circuitry to drive the gate which is different from the circuitry you are using to drive the base of your PNP.